# Return a single String from a dictionary using uniqueKeysWithValues

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dictionary, key

***Goal of the code:***

To assign a *struct* dictionary with *Strings* as Keys and *String Arrays* as values to a variable and then pull *one* (can be at random) specific String key value in the *String Array* and return that one String element in the underlying *String Array* so that it can be used elsewhere (potentially assigned to a label.text)

Essentially (please reference code below), I want to access ***one*** value at random in `myDictionary` using a specific key (`"keyOne"`), and pull, let's say, `"Value2"` then return only the string `"Value2"` from the underlying *String Array* associated with `"keyOne"` using indexing.

Errors are in the code below.

The issue I'm thinking is that I haven't figured out how to turn my final `var Testing = dict["keyOne"]` into an *Int compatible index*... if it was an index, the code would pull an Int value and the corresponding String from the three Strings in the underlying value array (due to the three String values associated with "keyOne").

Also, `variableView()` just inherits the datasource from several other containers, but the `var dataSource : Structure?` is the main reference, so that is what I included.

Code so far:

```
let myDictionary = [Structure(name: "keyOne", text: ["Value1", "Value2", "Value3"]), Structure(name: "keyTwo", text: ["Value4", "Value5", "Value6"])]

lazy var dict = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: myDictionary.lazy.map { ($0.name, $0.text) })
    
struct Structure: Hashable {
    
        var name: String
        var text: [String]
    
        init(name: String, text: [String]){
            self.name = name
            self.text = text
            
        }
    }

func variable(at index: Int) -> variableView {
        let variable = variableView()
        var Testing = dict["keyOne"]
        variable.dataSource = Testing![index] <- Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'structure'
            return variable

var dataSource : Structure? {
        didSet {
                label.text = "This is a test"
            } else {
                // n/a
            }
    }
```

Please note that the error message is above in the code for `variable.dataSource = Testing![index]`.

I am also suspecting that my issue lies in the "looping" logic of how I am assigning a variable with a struct, to a datasource which references that same struct.

Any help is appreciated as I have been stuck on this for legitimately a week (I truly have exhausted every single StackOverflow answer/question pair I could find).

**THANK YOU!**

***EDIT:***

I found this documentation to assist me greatly with this, and I recommend anyone with a similar question as mine to reference this: https://swift.org/blog/dictionary-and-set-improvements/

Comment: What is the actual meaning of the parameter `index`? Is it an index into `myDictionary` array? If so, why do you need `dict`? Or, for that matter, why do you need `Structure`?

Comment: The index is for a larger scope of the project (I plan on adding more complexities to the functionality, adding if-then statements which remove certain keys), and it needs to conform to these structures. Honestly, I'm at the point where I'm willing to hire a Developer to help me get this dream alive.

Comment: Also, it is to index the `myDictionary` yes, and if I'm going about that wrong, please help, as this honestly could be written incorrectly compared to the stated end goal. @NewDev

Comment: If it's an index into `myDictionary`, why not just get the structure object and its `.text` property directly, e.g. `let textArr = myDictionary[index].text` and then return the random element from that: `return textArr[textArr.indices.randomElement()!]` (I've simplified here with `!`)

Comment: Sir, this might be exactly what I'm looking for and to be completely honest, I'm a newbie at programming (Started this project over a year ago, worked diligently for 2-3 months, then life took over, now starting it back up) Do you do freelance work under contract for pay? I'm legitimately willing to get an experienced IOS developer and I'm willing to shell out good cash to help me. I work full-time and it's nearly impossible to learn code and simultaneously do this. Also wouldn't mind giving equity if this thing takes off.

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but I respectfully decline. There are plenty of places where you could find experienced iOS developers. Hope this helps you for now to get unblocked.

Comment: Completely understood! @NewDev Hate to bother you again, but the recommendation you gave yielded another error. Perhaps I left out an important bit of information, and that is that the `let variable = variableView()` is used in a myriad of different functions throughout the code. Basically, after pulling and assigning that text to a label.text, it uses that as an index to remove an Int atIndex from the `myDictionary` and loops through to find another unique value until the array is exhausted. Not sure if you could think of a way to get the `variable.dataSource = Testing![index]` to conform...

Comment: I also tried `variable.dataSource = myDictionary[index].text` and got the error *`Cannot assign value of type '[String]' to type 'Structure'*

Comment: To note though, `variable.dataSource = myDictionary[index]` works just fine. I need this as my end result, but be able to pull a specific key value in the underlying index then start pulling from that underlying key-value string array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the question *and* the discussion in the comments I would add a mutating func to the struct that removes and returns a random string

```
mutating func pullText() -> String? {
    guard let index = text.indices.randomElement() else {
        return nil
    }
    return text.remove(at: index)
}
```

Example

```
if let index = myDictionary.firstIndex(where: { $0.name == "keyOne" }), 
   let text = myDictionary[index].pullText() {
     someLabel.text = text
}
```

Here is another example based on the code in the question

Assuming VariableView looks something like this

```
struct VariableView: View {
    var dataSource : Structure?
    var word: String?
    var body: some View {
        Text(word ?? "")
    }
}
```

Then the func variable can be changed to

```
func variable() -> VariableView {
    var variable = VariableView()
    if let index = dict.firstIndex(where: { $0.name == "keyOne" }) {
        variable.dataSource = dict[index]
        variable.word = dict[index].pullText()
    }

   return variable
}
```

Comment: I really like this idea, as I can see where this is going to assist with further functionality in my project. However, the above yielded an error. I do see that you went straight to assigning the text to a label, but it is essential that this String conforms to and is able to be assigned to the `let variable = variableView()`, as this has tons of other functionality already built into it. Here is the code, and error in question: `let text = myDictionary[index].pullText() {                                  variable.dataSource = text` *<- Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'Structure'*

Comment: The above modification to the code got all of the code to compile correctly! THANK YOU! However, I'm running into one last issue when trying to assign the `variable.word` to the `label.text`, it says that the `word` is a `nil` value...? How do I modify the above to make sure it's not a `nil` value when I go to assign it to my label.text? Thinking it has to do with the variable function with `remove(at: index)`. I also tried to just `print(word)` and that's how I determined it was `nil` even after looping it through the function. @Joakim Danielson

Comment: `if let index = myDictionary.firstIndex(where: { $0.name == "keyOne" }) { word = myDictionary[index].pullText() }` Accessing `word` returns a nil value. when I do `label.text = word` Any idea why this is returning a nil value, when there is clearly three values under the `"keyOne"` key?

Comment: @CodeMan123 What has this got to do with my answer? I have no idea how/where `word` is declared in your code and where you do `label.text = word`

Comment: `var dataSource : Structure? { didSet { label.text = word } else { // n/a } }` This is where I do `label.text = word` @Joakim Danielson It is in the original post above. Also, you gave me where I declared it in the above code, I delcared `var word: String?` in `class VariableView : UIView {`

Comment: But `Structure` doesn't have a property `label` (this is why I ignored that code). If I do `let v = variable() print(v.word)` it works

Comment: Do I add `let v = variable()` to the structure where I have the `didSet`, or do I add this to the `func variable()`? I am extremely grateful that you are helping me through this, I feel like I'm on the last step and I can put this one to bed.

Comment: That was just a test I did in a playground, I have now also tested this as a proper view and run the app and it works there too for me. I have given you an answer to your question, I can not debug your code for you so you need to resolve this last bit yourself

Comment: Also, the property label is in the main class: `class VariableView : UIView { var label = UILabel()   var dataSource : Structure? {`

Comment: So, with the help of your post I was able to finally perform what I needed to. I ended up getting rid of my struct, and conforming it with some key variables you gave me above. I appreciate it, my apologies for asking so many questions. Thank you as well, New Dev

Comment: Thank you as well, @New Dev